# Python stream from FTP server to Flask server for downloading

Tags: python, flask, ftp, ftplib

I have a Python Flask app that gets request to download a file from a remote FTP server. I have used `BytesIO` to save contents of the file downloaded from FTP server using `retrbinary`:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, request, send_file
from ftplib import FTP
from io import BytesIO

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

@app.route('/download_content', methods=['GET'])
def download_content():
    filepath = request.args.get("filepath").strip()
    f = FTP(my_server)
    f.login(my_username, my_password)
    b = BytesIO()
    f.retrbinary("RETR " + filepath, b.write)
    b.seek(0)
    return send_file(b, attachment_filename=os.path.basename(filepath))

app.run("localhost", port=8080)
```

The issue here is that when the `download_content` route is hit, first the contents of the file comes in the `BytesIO` object, then it is sent to the frontend for downloading.

How can I stream the file to frontend while it is being downloading from FTP server? I can't wait for the file to get downloaded entirely in `BytesIO` object and then do a `send_file`, as that could be both, memory inefficient as well as more time consuming.

I have read that Flask's `send_file` accepts a `generator` object, but how can I make the `BytesIO` object `yield` to `send_file` in chunks?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you will need to setup a worker thread to manage the downloading from `retrbinary`

I have made a quick Gist for this as we have come across the same problem. This method seems to work.

https://gist.github.com/Richard-Mathie/ffecf414553f8ca4c56eb5b06e791b6f

```
class FTPDownloader(object):
  def __init__(self, host, user, password, timeout=0.01):
    self.ftp = FTP(host)
    self.ftp.login(user, password)
    self.timeout = timeout

  def getBytes(self, filename):
    print("getBytes")
    self.ftp.retrbinary("RETR {}".format(filename) , self.bytes.put)
    self.bytes.join()   # wait for all blocks in the queue to be processed
    self.finished.set() # mark streaming as finished

  def sendBytes(self):
    while not self.finished.is_set():
      try:
        yield self.bytes.get(timeout=self.timeout)
          self.bytes.task_done()
      except Empty:
        self.finished.wait(self.timeout)
    self.worker.join()

  def download(self, filename):
    self.bytes = Queue()
    self.finished = Event()
    self.worker = Thread(target=self.getBytes, args=(filename,))
    self.worker.start()
    return self.sendBytes()
```

Should probably add some timeouts and logic to handle connections timing out ect, but this is the basic form.

## Explanation

Queues don't guarantee that the worker process `getBytes` has finished when they are empty so you have to have a semaphore/Event to indicate to the generator `sendBytes` when the worker has finished. However I have to wait for all the blocks in the queue to be processed first hence the `self.bytes.join()` before setting finished.

Interested if anyone can think of more elegant way of doing this.