# How to download zip file through ajax call from Flask app method?

Tags: flask, python-requests, axios

I have a Flask method that gets url and returns the zip file's content. The content should be returned to the axios get method. Flask code:

```
zip_file = requests.get(url)
if zip_file.ok:
   return {
        'file': zip_file.content
  }
```

But it doesn't work, it fires exception 'TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable").

How to fix it? I saw some solutions with coding-decoding but I'm not sure how to use it, especially after the axios request gets the response (I can't use the direct link because of security reasons).

Comment: The issue is coming from that it's being dumped into a JSON and the zip file that you have is not in a format that's understood. 
Try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51024276/python-stream-from-ftp-server-to-flask-server-for-downloading

Comment: @mattsap Probably it's the reason but I still don't know how to solve it. Can you suggest some code?